# Make an object MAX_size at the bottom of eh screen and MIN_size at the top of the screen using processing

Tags: processing

```
final int MAX_SIZE = 500;
final int MIN_SIZE = 50;

void setup (){
    size(500,500);
}

void draw(){
    setSizeXAndY();
}

void setSizeXAndY(){
    size= (MAX_SIZE*mouseY)/(width); 
}
```

I need help with the arithmetic please for the size function please.

Comment: What does your code do that's different from what you expected?

Comment: it doesnt set miz size to 50 at the top of the canvas

Comment: What makes you believe that? You never use the `MIN_SIZE` variable for anything, so where do you think it should be used?

Comment: i tried using, put it in place of the width, but that's wrong. I just cant seem to figure it out, Ive tried various thing and im not supposed to use an if statement

Answer (score 1):

The code as you posted it makes very little sense in it's current form and has a syntax error (`size` isn't declared in `setSizeXAndY()` although you try to assign a value to it)
Unfortunately it doesn't communicate your intentions clearly.

The (misspelled) title provides more information but is also misleading: by object do you mean an instance of a [class](https://processing.org/reference/class.html) or a visual object to rendered on screen (e.g. rectangle/ellipse/etc.) ?

Your sketch is 500x500 pixels so you already have MAX_SIZE at the bottom (as you set it equal to 500). `MIN_SIZE` should be equal to 0 to be at the top. (e.g. `final int MIN_SIZE = 50;`)

Regarding arithmetic for the size function I guess you mean this:

```
size= (MAX_SIZE*mouseY)/(width);
```

I'm not sure this does what you expect to do, but you can do a bit of basic debugging and print your values out:

```
void setSizeXAndY(){
    int size = (MAX_SIZE*mouseY)/(width);
    println("MAX_SIZE",MAX_SIZE,"mouseY",mouseY,"width",width,size);
}
```

You'll notice a pattern:

```
MAX_SIZE 500 mouseY 258 width 500 258
MAX_SIZE 500 mouseY 258 width 500 258
MAX_SIZE 500 mouseY 258 width 500 258
MAX_SIZE 500 mouseY 258 width 500 258
```

`mouseY` is the same as `size` !

That is because you're sketch is 500x500 so `500 x mouseY / 500 = mouseX` (remember multiplication is commutative, you can change the order of the factors and the result will remain the same)

Maybe you mean inverting Y ? If so, you can simply subtract the Y value from the maximum Y value. Here's an example based on your code:

```
final int MAX_SIZE = 500;
final int MIN_SIZE = 50;

void setup () {
  size(500, 500);
}

void draw() {
  background(0);
  setSizeXAndY();
}

void setSizeXAndY() {
  int size = (MAX_SIZE*mouseY)/(width);
  println("MAX_SIZE", MAX_SIZE, "mouseY", mouseY, "width", width, size);

  // subtract value from it's maximum value "flips/mirrors" the value
  int invertedY = MAX_SIZE - mouseY;
  // test: draw the regular mouseY in green
  fill(0,192,0);
  ellipse(mouseX, mouseY, 18, 18);
  // test: draw the inverted mouseY in red
  fill(192,0,0); 
  ellipse(mouseX, invertedY, 18, 18);
}
```

Alternatively you can use [map()](https://processing.org/reference/map_.html) :

```
final int MAX_SIZE = 500;
final int MIN_SIZE = 50;

void setup () {
  size(500, 500);
}

void draw() {
  background(0);
  setSizeXAndY();
}

void setSizeXAndY() {
  int size = (MAX_SIZE*mouseY)/(width);
  println("MAX_SIZE", MAX_SIZE, "mouseY", mouseY, "width", width, size);

  // subtract value from it's maximum value "flips/mirrors" the value
  float invertedY = map(mouseY,0,MAX_SIZE,MAX_SIZE,0);
  // test: draw the regular mouseY in green
  fill(0,192,0);
  ellipse(mouseX, mouseY, 18, 18);
  // test: draw the inverted mouseY in red
  fill(192,0,0); 
  ellipse(mouseX, invertedY, 18, 18);
}
```

but it's worth learning and getting the hand of using basic arithmetic.

Learning to program can be frustrating at first but take your time with it, be patient and keep trying over and over again: you will eventually get it !

Take it one step at a time and make sure you fully understand a notion before moving to the next: understanding the fundamentals (variables (primitive types) / conditions / loops / arrays / functions ) is crucial. If you get these right, everything else will much much easier.

Try to write code everyday for at least half an hour / an hour outside of your homework: something fun you'd like to try.